# Flow complaining about action union type in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, flowtype

Flow throws 3 errors (property not found) for each parameter (action.location, action.weatherResult and action.error). The only solution I found is to not union and have just one action type with the 3 different properties as optional maybes but the properties aren't optional so it doesn't solve my problem.

*Actions*

```
// @flow
import actionTypes from './index';    

export type FetchWeatherStartAction = {
  type: string,
  location: string
};    

export type FetchWeatherSuccessAction = {
  type: string,
  weatherResult: ?string
};    

export type FetchWeatherFailAction = {
  type: string,
  error: string | false
};    

export type WeatherAction = FetchWeatherStartAction | FetchWeatherSuccessAction | FetchWeatherFailAction;    

const fetchWeatherStart = (location: string): FetchWeatherStartAction => ({
  type: actionTypes.WEATHER_FETCH_START,
  location
});    

const fetchWeatherSuccess = (weatherResult: ?string): FetchWeatherSuccessAction => ({
  type: actionTypes.WEATHER_FETCH_SUCCESS,
  weatherResult
});    

const fetchWeatherFail = (error: string | false): FetchWeatherFailAction => ({
  type: actionTypes.WEATHER_FETCH_FAIL,
  error
});    

export {
  fetchWeatherStart,
  fetchWeatherSuccess,
  fetchWeatherFail
}
```

*Action Types*

```
// @flow
const actionTypes = {
  WEATHER_FETCH_START: 'WEATHER_FETCH_START',
  WEATHER_FETCH_SUCCESS: 'WEATHER_FETCH_SUCCESS',
  WEATHER_FETCH_FAIL: 'WEATHER_FETCH_FAIL'
}    

export default actionTypes;
```

*Reducer*

```
// @flow
import actionTypes from './../actions';
import type { WeatherAction } from './../actions/weather';    

/*export type WeatherActionType = {
  type: string,
  error?: boolean | string,
  weatherResult?: string | null,
  location?: string
};*/    

export type WeatherStateType = {
  location: string,
  fetchedFromServer: boolean,
  isFetching: boolean,
  fetchError: boolean | string,
  weatherResult: ?string
};    

const defaultState: WeatherStateType = {
  location: 'Barcelona',
  fetchedFromServer: false,
  isFetching: false,
  fetchError: false,
  weatherResult: null
};    

const weather = (state: WeatherStateType = defaultState, action: WeatherAction): WeatherStateType => {    

  switch (action.type) {    

    case actionTypes.WEATHER_FETCH_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
        fetchError: false,
        location: action.location
      };    

    case actionTypes.WEATHER_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        fetchedFromServer: true,
        isFetching: false,
        fetchError: false,
        weatherResult: action.weatherResult
      };    

    case actionTypes.WEATHER_FETCH_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        fetchedFromServer: false,
        isFetching: false,
        fetchError: action.error
      };    

    default:
      return state;
  }    

};    

export default weather;
```

Comment: Please include enough of the imported `actionTypes` so that someone can run it to reproduce your exact errors.

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to rely on type information that is not actually encoded in your types.

For example in the definition of `FetchWeatherStartAction`:

```
export type FetchWeatherStartAction = {
  type: string,
  location: string
};
```

`type` is declared to be a `string`. Any string at all.

But later, in this switch case:

```
switch (action.type) {    
    case actionTypes.WEATHER_FETCH_START:
        ...
        action.location
        ...
```

You are expecting Flow to know that `FetchWeatherStartAction` is the *only* possible alternative of the `WeatherAction` enum which could have `'WEATHER_FETCH_START'` as the value of its `type` property. Based on the types alone, *any* action could have *any* value for its type. The only thing we can be sure about is that it's a string.

The solution is to define your action variants to have more specific types, which incorporate their legal values.

```
export type FetchWeatherStartAction = {
  type: 'WEATHER_FETCH_START',
  location: string
};    

export type FetchWeatherSuccessAction = {
  type: 'WEATHER_FETCH_SUCCESS',
  weatherResult: ?string
};    

export type FetchWeatherFailAction = {
  type: 'WEATHER_FETCH_FAIL',
  error: string | false
};
```

When you check that `type === 'WEATHER_FETCH_START'`, Flow can be *certain* that the actual type is `FetchWeatherStartAction`. This is possible because it already knows that `action` is a `WeatherAction` and `WeatherAction` is an enum with *only* those three possible values.

It's a little unfortunate that you have to repeat the string literals, rather than refer to a constant. I know people get uneasy about that, but I would argue in this case that all of the reasons why magic constants are considered bad practice are dealt with by Flow's type checking. In Javascript, using a syntactic identifier to access a field is semantically no different than accessing it by its string name.

Comment: This makes sense, I tried to assign the constant as the type of 'type' but that didn't work indeed. I'll consider replacing the constants with string literals. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumble upon this problem.

Root cause: [Flow](https://flow.org) will remove all refinements to the types when you do a function call.

Solution: Access the param before you make the function call

For example, in your case, the reducer can be written in this way:

```
const reducer = (state: {}, action: WeatherAction): WeatherStateType => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case actionTypes.WEATHER_FETCH_START:
          const {location} = action;
          return { ...state, isFetching: true, fetchError: false, location: location};
      case actionTypes.WEATHER_FETCH_SUCCESS:
          const {weatherResult} = action;
          return {...state, fetchedFromServer: true, isFetching: false, fetchError: false,, weatherResult: weatherResult};
      case actionTypes.WEATHER_FETCH_FAIL:
          const {error} = action;
          return {...state. fetchedFromServer: false, isFetching: false, fetchError: action.error};
      default: 
          return state
    }
}
```